# Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include "SortedList.h"

using namespace std;

#define BOUNDS 100

int main() {

    SortedList *list = new SortedList();  // points to the sorted list object
    Student *create[BOUNDS];  // array to hold 100 student objects
    int num = 100000;   // holds different ID numbers

    // fills an array with 100 students of various ID numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
        create[i] = new Student(num);
        num += 10;
    }

    // insert all students into the sorted list
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++)
    list->insert(create[i]);

    // removes each student from the list
    num = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
    list->remove(num);
    num += 10;
    }

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a seg fault with the previous code. Any insight as to why this is or how to possibly fix it would be appreciated. The seg fault is definitely caused by the `delete list;` line

UPDATE 1: Here is my SortedList destructor

```
/*
 * Destructs this sorted list object
 */
SortedList::~SortedList() {
    freeList(head);
}

/*
 * Traverses throught the linked list and deallocates each node
 */
void SortedList::freeList(Listnode *L) {
    Listnode *tmp = L;  //holds the node to be deleted

    //traverses the list
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        Listnode *next = tmp->next; //holds the value of the next node

    //delete previous node
    delete tmp->student;
    delete tmp->next;
    delete tmp;

    //sets the next node to the node to be deleted
    tmp = next;
    }
    //delete header node
    delete L;
}
```

Comment: `delete list` should call `~SortedList()`, so does the destructor do anything non-trivial?

Comment: I will post the SortedList destructor in a minute, if you care to look at it.

Comment: So one correction is to remove the line `delete tmp->next;` from `SortedList::freeList`. Is the assumption that the SortedList owns all the storage handed to it? If it does not own the space pointed at by `student`, then `delete tmp->student;` is probably not correct. It is not clear what SortedList::remove does. Does that remove the ListNode, or does it remove the ListNode and delete the `student` member? If it deletes the `student` member too, then it would be consistent with `SortedList::freeList`, otherwise it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `freelist()`, you delete `tmp->next`, then set `tmp = tmp->next`. Now `tmp` has an invalid pointer. You need to restructure your code so that you do not free a pointer before accessing its members.

Although I hate doing people's homework for them, here's my solution:

```
/*
 * Traverses throught the linked list and deallocates each node
 */
void SortedList::freeList(Listnode *L) {
    if(L == NULL) return;
    freeList(L->next);
    delete L->student;
    delete L;
}
```

This use O(n) stack space for deletion, but I personally find it much clearer than a loop. Your solution can be tweaked to "just work" by removing the call to `delete tmp->next`.

Comment: +1 Simple freeList() procedure. I'll delete my answer after you read the last comment.

Comment: While that works, it burns quite a lot of stack space for a data structure which can be traversed iteratively. The error in SortedList::freeList(Listnode *L) is in only deleting the same space twice.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we can't see `SortedList` or `Student`, and I'd guess the problem is in one of those. I note that `num` never gets reset to its original value after the creation loop, which means that most of the `remove` calls are going to be passed an id that belongs to no `Student`; perhaps that case fails. Or perhaps there are simply bugs in the `insert` or `remove` methods -- or the constructor or destructor, for that matter. It's totally up in the air.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, that destructor uses a pointer after it's been deleted; that could be the only source of error, or there could easily be more in the code we haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // removes each student from the list
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
    list->remove(num);
    num += 10;
    }
```

Looks interesting... how does this work exactly?  If num is 100000 + BOUNDS*10 at this point in the code (since it is never changed after you add 10 to it for each student you create).  Every remove call you make doesn't remove a student by their ID (since the id called is 100000 + BOUNDS*10 + i*10).  Was the intent to remove them by ID, if so you should consider resetting num to 100000 before doing the remove loop.

To clarify how this could cause the seg-fault:  if your remove function doesn't have proper bounds checking it could go out of the memory looking for the id to remove.

Updated with destructor question:

```
void SortedList::freeList(Listnode *L) {
    Listnode *tmp = L;  //holds the node to be deleted

    //traverses the list
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        Listnode *next = tmp->next; //holds the value of the next node

    //delete previous node
    delete tmp->student;
    delete tmp->next;
    delete tmp;

    //sets the next node to the node to be deleted
    //**********
    //Check here, you deleted next, but the assigned it to temp.  Tmp isn't null, but           
    //it is however, no longer your memory (since you deleted it)
    //**********
    tmp = next;
    }
    //delete header node
    delete L;
}
```